# Does Aurelia provide any kind of Dirty indicator based on the original value of the property

Tags: aurelia

I have an edit form and I want the Save button to be disabled until an edit is made to one of the properties bound to an input or select element.

However if the user edits the text back to the original value, the form should no longer be considered Dirty.

Example:

1. Original value: "Test" -- Not Dirty
2. User edits input and changes value to: "Test 2" -- Dirty
3. User edits input again and changes value back to "Test" -- Not Dirty

I saw [this](http://www.sobell.net/aurelia-dirty-checking-a-function-part-2/) post that describes how to create a dirtyBindingBehavior, but it only compares the new value to what was there previously -- in which case, line 3 above would result in still listing the form as Dirty since it would be comparing the old value of "Test 2" against the new value of "Test".

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to make a copy of the object and create a getter property that compares the old-object with the new-object (use `@computedFrom` to avoid dirty-checking). For instance:

```
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {

  oldModel = new Model();
  newModel = deepClone(this.oldModel);

  @computedFrom('newModel.name', 'newModel.surname')
  get hasChanged() {
    return !isEqual(this.oldModel, this.newModel);
  }

}

function deepClone(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));;
  //use Object.assign({}, obj) if you don't need a deep clone
}

function isEqual(obj1, obj2) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
}

class Model {
  //something from database;
  name = 'John';
  surname = 'Doe';
}
```

Running Example https://gist.run/?id=d9f7ee41f4448d7981351c7e222d7388

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark it as answer to help other people

Comment: In most cases you can just keep a serialized copy and compare it instead. Use only JSON.stringify in "deepClone" and store the string version in oldModel. Now implement "isEqual" with string comparision calling JSON.striginfy on newModel again.